# In IDA, what does the number of underscores prefixing a function name mean?

Tags: ida

In IDA, in the Functions subview, many functions have one or more underscores in their name. I'm guessing the number of underscores implies something. Does anyone know what the number of underscores indicate?

[image: underscores]

Comment: The function names here are not given by IDA (unless Lumia) - it is probably from the symbols in the binary. The _ doesn't mean anything in IDA context.

Comment: Function names in the binary, FLIRT signatures or a PDB, I reckon.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39625352/5431095).

These are not from IDA, but from the libraries used by the binary.

Comment: You can mark this as accepted